# Golang ListenAndServeTLS won't take my certificate

Tags: ssl, go, https

This has really stumped me...I'm just trying to setup a basic server using Cobra and the standard http package. I've followed the golang example [here](https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456) for how to create a certificate and key, but no matter what I throw at it, I'm not getting it to go through and keep getting this error:

> Cannot serve on http port: crypto/tls: failed to find certificate PEM data in certificate input, but did find a private key; PEM inputs may have been switched

so I am left with the belief that it must be something wrong with my program that won't let me process certificates.

This is what I use to parse my flags to start the server:

```
var serverCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "server",
    Short: "start a compiler server",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        addrUnsecure := ""
        addrSecure := ""

        addrUnsecure += ":" + strconv.FormatUint(serverPort, 10)
        addrSecure += ":" + strconv.FormatUint(securePort, 10)

        if noSSL {
            addrSecure = ""
        } else {
            if secureOnly {
                addrUnsecure = ""
            }
            if _, err := os.Stat(serverKey); os.IsNotExist(err) {
                log.Error("Can't find ssl key %s. Use --no-ssl flag to disable", serverKey)
                os.Exit(1)
            }
            if _, err := os.Stat(serverCert); os.IsNotExist(err) {
                log.Error("Can't find ssl cert %s. Use --no-ssl flag to disable", serverCert)
                os.Exit(1)
            }
        }

        server.StartServer(addrUnsecure, addrSecure, serverCert, serverKey)
    },
}

func addServerFlags() {
    serverCmd.Flags().Uint64VarP(&serverPort, "port", "p", setServerPort(), "set the listening port for http")
    serverCmd.Flags().Uint64VarP(&securePort, "secure-port", "s", setSecurePort(), "set the listening port for https")
    serverCmd.Flags().BoolVarP(&noSSL, "no-ssl", "n", setSSL(), "use only http")
    serverCmd.Flags().BoolVarP(&secureOnly, "secure-only", "o", setSecureOnly(), "use only https")
    serverCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&serverCert, "cert", "c", setDefaultServerCert(), "set the https certificate")
    serverCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&serverKey, "key", "k", setDefaultServerKey(), "set the key to interact with the https certificate")
}

func setServerPort() uint64 {
    return 9099
}

func setSecurePort() uint64 {
    return 9098
}

func setSSL() bool {
    return false
}

func setSecureOnly() bool {
    return false
}

func setDefaultServerCert() string {
    return ""
}

func setDefaultServerKey() string {
    return ""
}
```

and this is the function where the actual server is started:

```
func StartServer(addrUnsecure, addrSecure, key, cert string) {
    log.Warn("Hello I'm the marmots' compilers server")
    common.InitErisDir()
    // Routes

    http.HandleFunc("/", CompileHandler)
    // Use SSL ?
    log.Debug(cert)
    if addrSecure != "" {
        log.Debug("Using HTTPS")
        log.WithField("=>", addrSecure).Debug("Listening on...")
        if err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(addrUnsecure, cert, key, nil); err != nil {
            log.Error("Cannot serve on http port: ", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
    if addrUnsecure != "" {
        log.Debug("Using HTTP")
        log.WithField("=>", addrUnsecure).Debug("Listening on...")
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(addrUnsecure, nil); err != nil {
            log.Error("Cannot serve on http port: ", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}
```

I've gotten this in both Docker running Ubuntu 14.04 and OS X locally on my machine. Thanks in advance to whoever can help me out. It's kind of embarassing because this seems like it should be a really simple thing to do and I'm willing to bet it's going to be something dumb that's got me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`func StartServer(addrUnsecure, addrSecure, key, cert string) {`

so `key` is at 3. place, `cert` at 4. place in the parameter list.

`server.StartServer(addrUnsecure, addrSecure, serverCert, serverKey)`

Now you are calling that func with `cert` being at the 3. place and `key` at the 4. place.

Maybe swapping them will help.

Comment: wow...I feel incredibly dumb right now. Like I said...probably something dumb. Thanks a ton.